# Which of the following are true?.

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $\mathfrak{T}_1$ and $\mathfrak{T}_2$ are topologies on $X$ induced by metric $d_1$ and $d_2$, respectively, such that $\mathfrak{T}_1\subseteq \mathfrak{T}_2$. Then, which of the following statement is true?

- (a)If a sequence converges in $(X, d_2)$, then it converges in $(X, d_1)$
- (b)If a sequence converges in $(X, d_1)$, then it converges in $(X, d_2)$
- (c) Every open ball in $(X, d_1)$ is an open ball in $(X, d_2)$
- (d)The map $x\mapsto x$ from $(X, d_1)$ to $(X, d_2)$ is continuous

Intuitively, if a sequence convergent in weaker topology $\mathfrak{T}_1$, then it also convergent in $\mathfrak{T}_2$. So I think option (a) is correct.
(b) is false with the above idea.

I am confused with (c) and (d). Also, I am looking for a formal proof of statement (a).

Comment: Your reasoning would rather select option (b), wouldn't it?

Comment: Maybe it would help you to think about an example. Can you find one where $T_1$ and $T_2$ are not the same? For instance, $d_1$ is the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$ and can you give an example of $d_2$ different from $d_1$?

Comment: @Berci Yes, (b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

b has a simple counterexample ($d_1$ usual metric on $\Bbb R$, $d_2$ the discrete metric on that same set).

a is indeed true: if every open set under $d_2$ contains a tail of the sequence this certainly holds for all $d_1$-open sets, which are a subset. Note that the reaosn you give hasstronger/weaker in the wrong order: if you converge in the stronger, than also in the weaker. The weaker has fewer sets so fewer constraints.

c is false, same counterexample, or use even two equivalent metrics on the plane, like the taxicab and Euclidean one.

d is false, same counterexample, but true if you interchange domain and codomain.

The only place the metric places any role is in c.

Comment: You mean the topology induced by $d_2$ is finer than the topology induced by $d_1$ since the convergent sequence in discrete topology induced by $d_2$ is eventually constant, thus the sequence also convergent in topology induced by $d_1$, so we can find some sequence that convergent in the first topology but not second. Am I right?  I didn't downvote.

Comment: @AmanPandey ses the example I used for b.. as I said

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your counterexample.

Comment: @AmanPandey what didn’t you understand? Why $\mathfrak{T}_1$ is the usual topology on $\Bbb R$, $\mathfrak{T}_2$ the discrete topology on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: See my first comment...What I got from you I explained there.

Comment: @AmanPandey you first comment is about that in the larger topology only the eventually constant sequences converge. So that shows why b fails as $\frac1n$ converges for $d_1$ but not for $d_2$.

Comment: Thanks, Sir! ${}{}{}{}$